# Can't open hyperlinks in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

When a user clicks on hyperlinks in Outlook 2007, she receives the message:

> This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on
>   this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

I have:

1. Tried FixIt file from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310049
   without success.
2. Tried setting Internet Explorer as default browser without success.
3. Tried Resetting IE settings without success.
4. Tried repairing Office 2007 without success.
5. Tried System Restore, without success.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: "Please contact your system administrator." Is this a company PC? If yes then contact your IT department.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the free [Outlook Tweaker](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/ReliefJetTweakerOutlook/). It provides the "Repair Hyperlinks" functionality. Just close Outlook, run Tweaker as administrator and click the "Repair Hyperlinks" button. Please note that I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers.

Comment: Thanks thims. I'm waiting on the user to test. It would be good to receive feedback when pressing the button "fix hyperlinks" too. :-)